# file_get_contents(): No such host is known error

Tags: php, networking

I am using the `file_get_contents` function to get the URL into a string:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
```

But, I am getting the following error:

> file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

How can I solve this in my localhost?

Comment: I think this may be DNS or firewall issue. Can you check if you can `ping google.com` from that host?

Comment: `ping google.com` works in command line but getting same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your "localhost" cannot resolve the name google.com to an ip address, which means your machine doesn't/can't reach a valid dns server.
This probably doesn't only affect php. Try `ping google.com` on the console of that machine. Does this complain about the unknown host, too?
The steps necessary to solve the problem depend on what your "localhost" is (operating system, flavour/distribution, ...) and how it is connected to the internet.

Comment: when i give ping google.com it says unknown host. i check with my host. thanks.

Comment: `ping google.com` works in command line but getting same issue

Answer (score 3):

It is because you need to turn on allow_url_fopen in php.ini

Comment: That's not correct - if that was the case the server would return someting like "failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found" or "URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration"

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is Already ON but still not working

Answer (score 0):

Check your localhost and username.

Like if you are using Xampp, in the host column type `Localhost`
and the database name
and last but not least the username with  `root`, and then install.

It's quite easy but if you missing it, it's gone be very upsetting.